# UITableView doesn't pass touches through into custom row's controls, it selects row instead

Tags: ios, uitableview

I set up a UITableView with custom cells but I have found that UITableView, when I first tap it, wants to select the row. Whereas I want to tap what's in each cell.

Is there a way to tell UITableView to enter a mode where row selection does not occur?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show some code? What you are saying isn't the default behavior, as the cell view components being higher in the view hierarchy are supposed to (and do) handle the taps.

Answer (score 0):

`UITableViewCell` is a subclass of `UIView` so it has the property [`userInteractionEnabled`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIView) which you can set to NO when you create each cell.

***userInteractionEnabled***

*A Boolean value that determines whether user events are ignored and removed from the event queue. When set to NO, user events—such as touch and keyboard—intended for the view are ignored and removed from the event queue. When set to YES, events are delivered to the view normally. The default value is YES.*

Not sure if 'removed from the event queue' means the cell contents won't receive the touch response either.

Comment: `userInteractionEnabled` will cause even the contents of the cell to be disabled.